# Simple Gesture App Crashing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

All Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e11f533921aa4308e29d

I have been following Bucky's "Learn Android Dev". I wrote this code out originally myself, but when it crashed on startup I then copied Bucky's source code. I am using a tablet to run this app, but it crashes on both VM's and the tablet itself with the error

> Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped

Any ideas?

Comment: You should run the application in the debug mode and then look at what is the exact exception or error in the code causing the ANR.

Answer (score 0):

To use the GestureDetectorCompat class , you need to create an instance of the GestureDetectorCompat for your View. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html) documentation.

So the code will fail with null pointer and so you will get ANR at `this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);`

So in your onCreate method add following code, should solve your issue.

```
gestureDetector=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
```